# IBM Websphere MQ Server alternatives

Tags: biztalk, ibm-mq

Are there any alternatives to IBM Websphere MQ Server for Windows? We need to access a remote Queue Manager that doesn't support client connections (only Queue Manager to Queue Manager).

I've noticed that there are some BizTalk Host Integration adapters but they only seem to behave as clients (one transactional, the other non-transactional).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you need to talk to a z/OS QMgr because nearly all other platforms support client connections.  The short answer is no.  If the mainframe does not have Client Attach Facility (CAF) then it requires another QMgr to talk to it.

That said, it is very common that a mainframe QMgr won't accept a client connection as a matter of shop policy.  A standard pattern that is used in this case is that a QMgr on a distributed platform is used to accept the client connections and forward the messages to the mainframe, as well as to receive any replies.  Most shops in this category will have such a "client concentrator" QMgr for you to connect to.

If the QMgr you want to connect to is at another company, it is also very common to not allow client connections for security reasons.  In this case you would just need to bite the bullet and get a copy of WMQ.

Comment: Thanks for those insights. It seems like the last point is the one that applies to us.

Comment: If you proceed with WMQ, head over to http://t-rob.net/wmq for links to many resources, including the WMQ security presentation I give at conferences. If you run it on a Windows server, make sure the service ID is not an administrator. WMQ has a facility to trigger OS commands on arrival of a message and this can be exploited if the QMgr is not properly secured.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r4/html/ch6.chapt.html

just have look is it what you looking

Comment: Unfortunately that is for JBoss MQ, not Websphere MQ. Thanks anyways.